# Gamemaker Key Press Duration

Tags: game-maker

I am looking for a way to track the duration of a key press in gamemaker. I was looking into alarm functions, but I figured there's a more elegant way. How can I track the duration of a keypress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply have a variable that you will increment each step if the key is currently down, and read its value once the key is released.

Create event:

```
keyTimer = 0;
```

Step event:

```
if (keyboard_check(ord('A'))) {
    keyTimer += 1;
}
```

Key A Released event:

```
timePressed = keyTimer;
keyTimer = 0;
```

In this example, I am reading the time the user has pressed the A key and putting the value in the timePressed variable.